# ターミナルからRを起動できなくなった（dyld: Library not loadedになる）

Tags: macos, r

MacのターミナルからRを実行しようとしたところ、以下のようになってしまい、ターミナルからRを使うことができません。

```
$ r
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libreadline.6.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/XXX/opt/anaconda3/lib/R/lib/libR.dylib
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

他のサイトで以下を試すと良いとありましたが、相変わらず上記のエラーが出てきました。

```
conda update -c rdonnellyr -c main --all
```

ちなみにRstudioでは問題なくRを使えます。

macOSはCatalina ver10.15.6です。

良い解決法をご存知ないでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

小文字のr

```
r
```

は、zshではデフォルトで「直前のコマンドをもう一度」コマンドとなっています。
(MacOS Catalina からは、bash に変わり zsh が標準となっています)

Rは大文字表記がコマンド名です

```
R
```

でしたら起動出来たかと思います。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。質問当時の環境は、zshをbashに変更して運用しておりました。やっぱりzshに戻そうかなと思っていたので勉強になりました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: 今は解決されたとの事ですが、確実なのは R --version と実行すれば、実際に動いていたコマンドが確認出来たかと思います。なにかの参考になれば幸いです。

Comment: ありがとうございます！参考にさせていただきます！

Answer (score 1):

自己解決できたようなので、手順を書いておきます。正しいかどうか不明ですが、、、

以下手順です。

前述の

```
Referenced from: /Users/XXX/opt/anaconda3/lib/R/lib/libR.dylib
Reason: image not found
```

を参考に、

```
/Users/XXX/opt/anaconda3/lib/R/lib/libR.dylib
```

のR以下のディレクトリを削除しました。

さらにRとAnaconda3をアンインストールし、RとAnaconda3を再インストールしました。

その後、ターミナル上から

```
$R　もしくは　r
```

とすると、無事Rを起動させることができるようになりました。

改善点などがあればお手数ですがご教示いただけますと幸いです。

ありがとうございました。